# Matlab comparison with NaN values in different positions

Tags: matlab, matrix, nan

I'm trying to compare two vectors with `NaN` values in different position. 
I need to consider these vectors equal
for example

```
a = [NaN 2 3 4];
b = [1 NaN 3 4];
```

I tried

```
isequalwithequalnans(a,b)
```

but it returns zero as the position of `NaN` elements in the array does matter.
Is there any way to do this

Answer (score 2):

### Approach 1

Obtain a [logical index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) with the positions where none of the vectors contain `NaN`,  and compare only those entries:

```
ind = ~(isnan(a)|isnan(b)); 
result = all(a(ind)==b(ind));
```

### Approach 2

Use the fact that [`max`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) and [`min`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) ignore `NaN`s when compared with numeric values:

```
result = isequaln(max(a,b), min(a,b));
```

Note that [`isequaln`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isequaln.html) is used to treat `NaN`s as equal. This is necessary in case `a` and `b` contain a `NaN` in the same position.